# LLVM and dwarf debugging information

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, dwarf

I'm trying to retain DWARF debugging information during the LLVM optimizations, my question is: can I insert somehow the debugging information for every instruction in LLVM? Will LLVM keep these information when doing all the optimization passes and then dump me a DWARF annotated LLVM optimized IR?

I believe that if this works, I can have a back-end (which supports those debugging info of course) generate final end-code that will be (more or less due to optimizations) debuggable with the source code, am I correct?

Comment: I'm working on a similar thing, I believe you should disable some transformation passes to retain all the debugging infos, otherwise some will be lost

Answer (score 5):

Optimized debug info is still a pretty new area for llvm. It's under active development, but a lot of it depends on what you're looking for. Precise variable tracking isn't really there as it undergoes transformations - variable information is occasionally lost. The SROA pass is particularly bad about it at the moment.

That said, if you're looking for line information and type information you should be fine. Arguments should be reasonably good so you won't have too many of them "optimized out" by the passes.

As far as how to annotate your source code the easiest thing is to look into what clang emits for IR and debug metadata. Make sure to use the DIBuilder class to handle most things, and pay attention to how locations are attached to IR level instructions as well. Most of that code is in clang/lib/CodeGen/CGDebugInfo.cpp.

Hope this helps and feel free to ask on the llvm-dev or cfe-dev mailing lists if you have any questions.

Comment: Is there any effort underway to make llvm as capable as gcc -fvar-tracking-*?

Comment: There is, yes. Optimized debug info is an area that's "next" on the debug info route as optimization quality is being improved. See the recent work by Adrian Prantl on dealing with SROA'd code and mem2reg.

Comment: Here's the link to [clang/lib/CodeGen/CGDebugInfo.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CGDebugInfo.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

LLVM [already supports dwarf-like annotations in the IR](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html) which, when compiled, get generated as dwarf sections in the binary. All optimizations attempt to preserve this information, though it isn't always guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you by my side, I'm interested in this as well :)